# Given the name of an excel cell, how can i find its value?

Tags: .net, vb.net, excel

So in excel, you can assign cells names to avoid using Row and Column numbers. In this case, this is especially useful because I'm dealing with several excel sheets and do not know where this particular cell will be.

How can I get the value of this cell? I'm currently looping through the entire worksheet looking for it, but I stumbled across this online, which would speed up my application considerably.

If found posts online that suggest either `xlWorkSheet.Cells("CellName").Value` or `xlWorkSheet.GetCell("CellName").Value`. Unfortunately the cells method does not accept a string as an argument and the GetCell method does not exist. I'm using the interop library. Thank you in advance.

Comment: What does the loop code look like?  What's the string that you're trying to look up as the cell value?

Comment: When I have these kinds of issues, I usually set a break point, go into debug, and then add the object in question to the watch.  So for example, add xlWorkSheet to the watch, then expand the arrow down and start exploring the child objects until you find what you are looking for.

Comment: @user3578951 Its a couple of nested for loops, nothing fancy. Just has a huge runtime

Comment: Have you tried `xlWorkSheet.Range`? Despite it's name, it can return a single named cell.

Comment: @Ken White, that was it, thank you kindly

Comment: Worksheet.Range will only return the name if you are on the right worksheet, if you search a whole workbook you have to use the names collection of the workbook. Don't know who downvoted, but they are ignorant

Answer (score -1):

EDIT: `Range("MyName")` is one way, but if you're in VBA, the shortest way to get the value of a range is to use the `Evaluate` function shorthand: `[MyName]` this will effectively return the Named Range called `MyName`

[image]

or from powershell (which also uses COM like .NET):

```
$Excel.Evaluate("MyName").Value()
```

Original answer:
Have you tried worksheet.names and workbook.names

`ThisWorkbook.Names("MyName").RefersToRange.Value`

Proof this also works through COM automation / VSTO / Powershell:

[image: Powershell screenshot]

```powershell
$file = "C:\Users\Vincent\Desktop\test.xls"

$Excel = New-Object -ComObject excel.application
$Excel.visible = $false
$Workbook = $Excel.Workbooks.open("C:\Users\Vincent\Desktop\test.xls") 
$Workbook.Names.Item("MyName").RefersToRange.Value()
```

also note that the scope of the named range matters in how you access it:

[image: Name Manager scope]

Comment: funny this gets downvoted when it will help you get more consistent results in case Named ranges have a different scope...